# Naming a merge with Sourcetree

Tags: git, merge, atlassian-sourcetree

Using Sourcetree, I'm wondering if there is a way for naming `merge` (as it is possible to do on GitHub for example) to avoid having very many occurrences of the same:

> Merge branch '`feature`' into `master`

The [documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/get-started-with-sourcetree/merge-changes-from-one-branch-to-another-git-847359121.html), last modified on Sep 37 (**sic**), 2016, seems quite silent on this possibility.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To create a commit message for a merge in source tree, you can perform the merge and commit separately.

First, select the commit you want to merge and choose `Repository > Merge...` from the menu.

In the resulting dialog:

1. Ensure that `Commit merge immediately (if no conflicts)` is **not** checked
2. Click `OK`

[image]

Resolve any conflicts if necessary, then you'll complete the commit on the merge:

1. Click `Commit` in the ribbon
2. Enter your desired commit message
3. Click `Commit`

[image]

Of course, if you're feeling more adventurous, the fastest way to do this is to open the terminal and use the merge command with a message specified:

For a short message
`git merge -m "Your message" <branch>`

For a longer message (opens your default editor)
`git merge --edit <branch>`

Comment: Your answer seems to match accurately to what I want to do. I will test this method the next time I have to merge a branch and I will upvote if all works as expected.

Comment: I have just tested the method you described above, but I think I have maybe missed a step.

Indeed, after having performed the merge (with `Commit merge immediately (if no conflicts)` not checked), the branch where I want to merge my commit seems only to be pushed to the selected commit (this behaviour really looks like a push more than a merge).

I don't know if I have misunderstood something or if it is a problem with my version of SourceTree (2.3.1.0).

Comment: Unchecking `Commit merge immediately` prevents git from creating the commit, instead it completes the merge in your working copy and stages the changes. You should see this in your history as uncommitted changes. This allows you to complete the commit yourself so you can create your own message instead of using the default merge commit.

Comment: I have found the problem (and the solution). 

To correctly use your method, I had to check the option `Create a new commit even if fast-forward is possible`.

Without that, when I return in the file status tab, I don't have anything to commit : the pointer only move to the last commit merged in the branch without any other possible action.

Maybe you have forgotten to add this step in your snapshot (or perhaps you achieve naming a merge without this option checked, but it doesn't seem to work for me).

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by amending the commit right after the merge is complete.  (Obligatory: Only do this BEFORE pushing to a remote.)

Click "Commit" in the main toolbar, and then click the "Commit options" drop down on the right side.  Check the option to "Amend latest commit."

Now type in your new message and click "Commit."  The merge commit will be updated with the new message.

Comment: Your answer appears to a good addition to the [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46249031/4094098). It's a fine trick to keep in mind, in case of forgetting the way to name properly a merge commit.